# Does VBScript have a way to reset HTML forms?

Tags: html, forms, vbscript

My client has chosen VBScript over JavaScript and there is no convincing them otherwise. They have a form that submits to a database, and there is a reset button to clear the form, but they want the form to clear after the data has been submitted to the database.

Is there any way in VBScript to clear a form when the user clicks Submit? I'm thinking of something similar to JavaScript when you unload the page to go to a Thank You page, it clears the form.

Comment: @SteveWellens - That doesn't answer my question. A simple "yes" or "no" would have been better.

Comment: @Lou = I didn't post an answer, I posted a comment.

Comment: @SteveWellens - Ok...That "comment" doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Diodeus - I realize you are trying to be funny, however, at the moment, I'm not seeing the humor. If you don't have an answer, please don't leave unhelpful comments. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is possible to interact with the DOM via VBscript. Have you seen this?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best answer but you could call javascript functions from your vbscript. Whats the reason they want vbscript only?

Comment: They want to maintain the site themselves, but they only know VBScript and are very limited in their VBScript knowledge. They only know how to do simple functions like Date(), MsgBox(), and CreateObject(). I told them JavaScript would be more versatile, but they don't want to learn another language or pay more for someone to upkeep.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is more tedious to clear a form with VBScript this way rather than using JavaScript, if you are forced to use VBScript, this is an alternative:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
      Option Explicit

      Sub cmdSubmit_onClick
        Dim strFullName

        strFullName = sample.name.value

        If strFullName = "" then
          MsgBox "Please enter your name."
          exit sub
        end if

        MsgBox "Your name is " & strFullName & "."

        sample.name.value = ""

      End Sub
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
<form name="sample">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="button" name="cmdSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Resetting the input value to "" will clear the form once the script is done running.